# Finding a matrix to use with the discrete fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider a sequence $x = \{ x_n \} _{n=0} ^{N-1}$ with discrete fourier transform denoted by 
$X = \{X_k \}_{k=0}^{N-1}$. If $x = (1, -i , 2, 3)$ then find the matrix which maps $x$ to $X$ and compute $X$ to find the discrete fourier transforms of $\overline{x}, \text{Re} (x),$ and $\text{Im} (x)$. (Here, the overline denotes pointwise complex conjugate.)

The only thing I can think of is to use the Vandermonde matrix for the roots of unity, up to the normalization factor, but I do not see how this would give such a matrix. Is there another way to go about this or any ideas on how to proceed? There is a somewhat similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750952/what-is-the-relationship-between-x-and-discrete-fourier-transform-of-overlin) that analyzes $\overline{x}$ only, but it does not utilize matrices).

Comment: You're almost there, by using the Vandermonde matrix with a fourth root of unity...  each term is denoted by $\omega^{r c}$, for $\omega$ a fourth root of unity, and $r$ and $c$ the row and column, respectively.  Then just do the matrix multiplication by the vector $(1, -i, 2, 3)^T$.